# How to load many .npy files very fast

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, numpy

I have to load many .npy files into memory. Each of the files holds a numpy array and has a size of about 3-6 MiB.

I am already able to load those files in parallel using numpy.load but in my opinion it still takes way too long.

Code sample:

```
import threading 
import numpy as np

def load_chunk(ch, idx, results):           
    # ch is a chunk of filenames to load
    ars = []
    for fn in ch:
        ars.append(np.load(fn))
    results[idx] = ars

threads = [None] * len(fn_ch)
all_results = [None] * len(fn_ch)

for i in range(len(fn_ch)):
    t = threading.Thread(target=load_chunk, args=(fn_ch[i], i, all_results))
    t.start()
    threads[i] = t

[t.join() for t in threads]
```

There are no infrastructure bottlenecks. When executing the code the CPU and the available disk IOPS are not utilized at all.

The workload is spread across 40 threads - increasing this number to 80 or decreasing ot to 20 has no effect on the loading time.

Is there any way to speed up the process?

Comment: In stead of multi-threading. i would try multiprocessing. Namely, I would use mpi4py library and exploit mpi functions to load several files in parallel.

Comment: I think that loading from many files is very slow for many times of IO in disk. Reducing the number of files or times of IO is best. For example, you can save your array to strings, then save them to one binary file.

Comment: thanks @freude. multiprocessing is the way to go.

Comment: would be interested to read your answer to your own question !